# What is @ in Julia?

Tags: syntax, julia

Recently I started learning Julia and have studied a lot of examples. I noticed the `@` sign/syntax a couple of times. Here is an example:

```
using DataFrames
using Statistics
df = DataFrame(x = rand(10), y = rand(10))

@df df scatter(:x, :y)
```

This will simply create a scatterplot. You could also use `scatter(df[!, :x], df[!, :y])` without the `@` and get the same result. I can't find any [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/search/?q=%40) about this syntax. So I was wondering what this syntax is and when you should use this in `Julia`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do not know how something works try typing `?` followed by what you want to know in Julia REPL.

For an example typing `?@` and pressing ENTER yields:

> The at sign followed by a macro name marks a macro call. Macros provide the ability to include generated code in the
> final body of a program. A macro maps a tuple of arguments, expressed as space-separated expressions or a
> function-call-like argument list, to a returned expression. The resulting expression is compiled directly into the
> surrounding code. See Metaprogramming for more details and examples.

Macros are a very advanced language concept. They generally take code as an argument and generate new code that gets compiled.
Consider this macro:

```
macro myshow(expr)
  es = string(expr)
  quote
    println($es," = ",$expr)
  end
  end
```

Which can be used as:

```
julia> @myshow 2+2
2 + 2 = 4
```

To understand what is really going try @macroexpand:

```
julia> @macroexpand @myshow 2+2
quote
    Main.println("2 + 2", " = ", 2 + 2)
end
```

You can see that one Julia command (2+2) has been packed around with additional julia code. You can try `@macroexpand` with other macros that you are using.

For more information see the [Metaprogramming](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/) section of Julia manual.

Answer (score 5):

What is @ in Julia?

> Macros have a dedicated character in Julia's syntax: the @ (at-sign), followed by the unique name declared in a macro NAME ... end block.

So in the example you noted, the `@df` is a macro, and the `df` is its name.
Read [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#man-macros) about macros. This concept belongs to the [meta-programming feature of Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Metaprogramming). I guess you used the `StatsPlots.jl` package since `@df` is one of its prominent tools; using the [`@macroexpand`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@macroexpand), you can investigate the functionality of the given macro:

```
julia> using StatsPlots

julia> @macroexpand @df df scatter(:x, :y)
:(((var"##312"->begin
          ((var"##x#313", var"##y#314"), var"##315") = (StatsPlots).extract_columns_and_names(var"##312", :x, :y)
          (StatsPlots).add_label(["x", "y"], scatter, var"##x#313", var"##y#314")
      end))(df))
```